# Javascript timer that restarts on key up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

O, so i have a 'live search' ajax search, which currently runs an sql search (via ajax) on each key up.

What i would prefer is to:

*run an sql search after a key has not been pressed for say 800 milliseconds*

.

*So i want to have a timer that is started on key up,
if the timer reaches 800ms then the ajax is called,
if a new keyup event occurs the timer is restarted*

how would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent plugin [TypeWatch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch) you may take a look at (IIRC StackOverflow uses this for the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page). Here's a sample usage:

```
$("#textId").typeWatch({ 
    highlight: true,
    wait: 800,
    captureLength: -1,
    callback: function() {
        // changed text
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(function () {

var theTimeout;

function doSearch() {
  // Do Search
};

$('#theField').bind('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(theTimeout);

  theTimeout = setTimeout(doSearch, 800);
});

}())
```

Comment: Might be an idea to namespace the global variable too, but it's surely op's job to do it :)

Comment: The variable isn't global, it's in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, my solution was this:

```
var doAjax = 0
$("input#name").keyup(function(){
    doAjax++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        doAjax--;
        if(doAjax>=1){
           return;
        } 
        $.post("do_ajax", { ...
```

I don't if it is the best solution, but it works :)